# How is it possible for a laptop to even have so much memory?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I was messing with malloc calls, and I wondered how much memory could my OS give me. I tried:

```
int main() {
    char *String = 0;
    String = malloc (100000000000000); // This is 10^14
    if (String)
        printf ("Alloc success !\n");
    else
        printf ("Alloc failed !\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And... It worked. 10^14 is roughly 18 Terabytes. Is it even possible for a laptop to have so much memory?
If that's not possible how can this be explained?

Comment: It's virtual memory, not real memory.

Comment: And just for experiment, try writing it.

Comment: Google "optimistic memory allocation".

Comment: `String = malloc (100000000000000);` -- try -->> `String = malloc (100000000000000ull);` or `String = calloc (1000000, 100000000);` , if you like tea ...

Comment: What does this imply ?

Comment: It means you're headed for a crash when you try to use the space.  For some reason, Linux thinks it is fun to let you allocate more space than your program can really have.

Comment: An OS might serve the allocation request by virtual memory that is not actually backed by physical memory. Means, your `malloc()` might succeed, but actually *using* that memory fails.

Comment: @DevSolar I see, thanks !

Comment: @wildplasser `calloc` would actually _use_ the memory to write zeroes to it, so it's not the same.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre :yes, that was my intention. Time for a nice cup of tea!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A system can discard zeroed pages though.

Comment: @wildplasser i tried the 100000000000ull and it also worked.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think that if the pages are not dirtied,they just keep the COW-bit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `calloc` wouldn't try to write anything. It would likewise request fresh virtual memory with (nonexistent) mappings to pages filled with zeroes.

Comment: @wildplasser: Adding a suffix shouldn't make any difference. An integer constant is always of a type big enough to hold its value. `100000000000000` will typically be of type `long` or `long long`, and will be converted to `size_t` when passed to `malloc` (assuming a proper declaration of `malloc` is visible, which is not the case in the OP's code).

Comment: My bad. I am still in the "all integer literals are int" larval stage.

Comment: @DevSolar Just to be clear: modern systems with paging could write all 18TB in principle if the hard drive was large enough. The limitation isn't physical memory, it's the size of the backing store. Individual pages of the virtual address space will be backed on-demand when necessary- first in physical memory, then swapped to the backing store when physical memory is full.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 64-bit OS can generate massive amounts of address space. What would limit it?

Backing of address space with physical memory (RAM) is only done when needed.

All the `malloc` call has to do is return an address. That address need not refer to physical memory until you try to read from it or write to it.

The downside of this behavior is that failing the `malloc` call is the usually the implementation's only chance to tell you nicely that you can't have the memory you are asking for. After this, about all the system can do is terminate the process when it tries to use more memory than the system can back.

Your implementation almost certainly gives you some way to control this behavior either at system level, for each process, or both.

Comment: Sometimes it is not even backed...

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, with the malloc call, I only get address to write to. But if i were to actually write to these location, I will not be able to write to all of them because i won't have actual memory left, right ?

Comment: @Jenkinx Right. The system has overcommitted. This behavior is configurable on many systems. My personal preference, after decades of experience, is to allocate sufficient paging/swap space and disable overcommittment. That isn't always possible though.

Comment: It is important to understand, @Jenkinx, that you're asking about implementation details.  C does not have a concept of successfully allocating a block of memory that you might not actually be able to use fully.  But yes, some implementations do exhibit that behavior under some circumstances.

Comment: This answer would benefit from briefly mentioning virtual address space and resident memory.